# Kinovea App | Desktop App sending exit code 0

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, exit-code, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run this github C# desktop application, but when I run it always says exit with code 0. I am expecting a GUI but nothing comes but this error. Your assistance is required. Here is the link to the github
[KinoveaApp](https://github.com/Kinovea/Kinovea)

Comment: Have yo uset the Kinovea project as startup project?

Comment: Yes I set it as a single startup project.